# Changer numbers of columns in woocommerce shop

Tags: customization, woocommerce-offtopic, columns

I have a problem with my shop columns in WooCommerce.

I would like to display 4 columns in my shop but unfortunately there is just 3 columns.

I use the Storefront theme for my shop, so I have looked the `storefront-template-fonction.php` file and the different `apply_filters` are setting up on 'columns'=>4.

Exemple:

```
$args = apply_filters( ‘storefront_popular_products_args’, array(
‘limit’   => 4,
‘columns’ => 4,
‘title’   => __( ‘Fan Favorites’, ‘storefront’ ),
) );
```

The only "solution" I have found is to used the shortcode `[recent_products per_page="12" columns="4"]`.

But with that, I have another problem, I have the 4 columns that I wanted with my products but the 3 previous columns displayed below too.

I work in Local with an Uwamp server and the last update of WordPress, Storefront and WooCommerce.

I hope there is somebody who can help me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this in `functions.php` file. It is better to create site specific plugins.

```
add_filter( 'storefront_loop_columns', 'sf_columns_per_row' );
function sf_columns_per_row() {
    return 4;
}
```

Comment: Hello, I've tried your code but unfortunately I have no difference. Any others ideas ?

Comment: Hello, I had an update this afternoon and your code resolve my problem finally. Thanks a lot for your help.

Answer (score 1):

Use this in functions.php file.

```
// Change number or products per row to 3
add_filter('loop_shop_columns', 'loop_columns');
if (!function_exists('loop_columns')) {
    function loop_columns() {
        return 3; // 3 products per row
    }
}
```

or use the WooCommerce shortcodes on your archive page:

```
[recent_products per_page="12" columns="5"]
```